# make: *** No rule to make target '~/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.0.0/lib/ruby/include/ruby/ruby.h', needed by 'amatch_ext.o'.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, jrubyonrails

I installed `jruby-9.2.0.0` on my ubuntu machine and my rails application use `rails 3.1.12` version, I am trying to run my app on jruby and when I tried to install all gems using `bundle install`command, I got an error for one `gem 'amatch'`

```
current directory: /home/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.0.0/gems/amatch-0.4.0/ext
```

/home/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.0.0/bin/jruby -r ./siteconf20181018-3341-1y55yce.rb extconf.rb
    creating Makefile

```
current directory: /home/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.0.0/gems/amatch-0.4.0/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.0.0/gems/amatch-0.4.0/ext
make "DESTDIR="
make: *** No rule to make target '/home/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.0.0/lib/ruby/include/ruby/ruby.h', needed by 'amatch_ext.o'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2
```

Please help me fix this error. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `amatch` gem uses a native extension which are [not supported](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/C-Extension-Alternatives) on JRuby.

If you really want to use JRuby, the only solution will be to replace that gem with another one.

Comment: There are a lot of gems in my app that uses a native extension, is there any way to resolve this problem

Comment: Not really, no. You could have a look at [Truffle](https://github.com/oracle/truffleruby) but it's not really ready for production use yet.

Comment: most gems with native extensions have a Java (native JRuby) version - opposed to MRI's C exts. so you do not need to worry about every gem, just the ones that are solely MRI centric. amatch seems to not pull in any libraries - so a JRuby port would be pretty straightforward (translating C code into Java and using JRuby APIs).